# Add color to white bounce area of UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to add a beige color to the bounce white space area that appears when dragging this WebView off screen. I've tried setting the WebView and WebView.ScrollView background colors manually and also setting them to transparent with opaque set to false having the ViewController's view background color set to beige - no luck. I also read in some of the objective-C iOS threads that adding a SubView with the background color I want to the WebView would do the trick, but could not get this to work in Mono.

The background of the Web content has been set in the HTML code of the document.

I wish I could post an example image, but don't have 10 rep yet. Feel free to ask for a better description.

Can anyone shed some light on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the background colour of my webView to clearColor in my nib file and for me it works fine:

[image]

[image]

Let me know if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: D'oh.. color was invalid. That method DID work, my own mistake. Cheers.